# How to test url string using regular expression

Tags: regex

Below is my code

```
/config\/info\/newplan/.test(string)
```

which will return true when find  /config/info/newplan/ in string.

However, I would like to test different condition in the same time like below

```
/config\/info\/newplan/.test(string) || /config\/info\/oldplan/.test(string) || /config\/info\/specplan/.test(string)
```

which will return true if the string end up with either "newplan" or "oldplan" or "specplan"

My question is how to make a better code and not write "/config/\info/\xxxx\ so many times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an [**alternation group**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html):

```
/config\/info\/(?:new|old|spec)plan/.test(string)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rUi4K8/1).

**Pattern details**:

- `config\/info\/`   - a literal `config/info/` substring
- `(?:new|old|spec)` - a [*non-capturing group*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-what-does-a-question-mark-followed-by-a-colon) (where `|` separates alternatives) matching any one of the substrings: `new`, `old` or `spec`
- `plan` - a literal `plan` substring

Answer (score 1):

this would be your bet

```
config\/info\/(newplan|oldplan|specplan)\/
OR
config\/info\/(newplan|oldplan|specplan)\/.test(string)
```

please see the example at [https://regex101.com/r/NyP1HP/1] as it doesn't allow other possibilities like following

```
/config/info/new1plan/
/config/info/newoldplan/
/config/info/specplan1/
```